# Site will not work with www,only with name.com

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have set a website buckets on amazon s3 with the following guide :
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/swh/getting-started-hosting-your-website.html

Than in `go daddy` , i have set 2 things :

in `CName` under the `www` i changed to `name.com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`.

Than in the name servers i have added the 4 names from amazon (NS-xxx.AWSDNS-xx.ORG )

Whats happen is that the site is working, but only with `name.com` , if i do `www.name.com`   :

```
The specified bucket exists in another region. Please direct requests to the specified endpoint.
endpoint:www.name.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 0):

1) check your dns name

2) you may be need added record DNS www IN CNAME domain.com.

3) contact to hosting provider.

the hosting company just set up the example.com on the server and did not set up the www.example.com so this is why it is not working as it doesn't exist.

Send them an email asking for the www. top be added to the server.

Comment: i can now see that the CNAME in go daddy should be www.name.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com   ,and not name.com . could this be the problem here ?

Answer (score 0):

Solve.
Set the CNAME in go daddy to the full domain not the root domain :

```
www.name.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com
```